# Qual criptografia usada pelo Asp.net Identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Ao criarmos um usuário usando Asp.net Identity, ele gera um Hash, até mesmo existe uma coluna no banco de dados com o nome de PasswordHash

Minha dúvida é, que tipo de Hash é gerado ? Qual criptografia usa o Asp.net Identity ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usa uma [Função de Derivação de Chaves](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h83s4e12%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), conforme especificação do [RFC 2898](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt). O processo é bastante intrincado e garante uma senha segura.

Codificação:

```
public static string HashPassword(string password)
{
    byte[] salt;
    byte[] buffer2;
    if (password == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
    }
    using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes bytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, 0x10, 0x3e8))
    {
        salt = bytes.Salt;
        buffer2 = bytes.GetBytes(0x20);
    }
    byte[] dst = new byte[0x31];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, dst, 1, 0x10);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer2, 0, dst, 0x11, 0x20);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(dst);
}
```

Verificação de Hash:

```
public static bool VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedPassword, string password)
{
    byte[] buffer4;
    if (hashedPassword == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (password == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
    }
    byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(hashedPassword);
    if ((src.Length != 0x31) || (src[0] != 0))
    {
        return false;
    }
    byte[] dst = new byte[0x10];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 1, dst, 0, 0x10);
    byte[] buffer3 = new byte[0x20];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0x11, buffer3, 0, 0x20);

    using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes bytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, dst, 0x3e8))
    {
        buffer4 = bytes.GetBytes(0x20);
    }
    return ByteArraysEqual(buffer3, buffer4);
}
```

O algoritmo ainda usa uma semente (salt) que garante que a geração do hash não vai acontecer duas vezes da mesma forma. Ao criar o usuário, o salt é salvo junto com a senha para o processo de verificação.

Comment: mesmo com essa geração desse hash, seria preciso ou necessário criptografar a senha do usuário ? Ou seja, criptografa a senha e gera o hash com a senha criptografada

Comment: A geração do Hash faz parte da criptografia da senha.