# Como gerar um hash para a senha do usuário com ASP.NET MVC e .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou implementando uma funcionalidade de autenticação / registro de usuários com ASP.NET MVC 4.5, mas não encontro em lugar algum uma maneira mais correta de trabalhar com senhas no banco de dados, eu não quero simplesmente gerar um MD5 e gravar no banco.

Não existe nenhuma classe padrão do ASP.NET que me possibilite gerar um hash ou verificar uma senha com um hash já existente? (Gerar / Verificar), assim como existe em frameworks PHP, por exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Existem várias. [Uma pesquisa no NuGet sobre BCrypt traz uma variedade delas](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=bcrypt).

[O algoritmo do ASP.NET Identity para senhas está aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43606/qual-criptografia-usada-pelo-asp-net-identity/43607#43607).

Você ainda pode usar o algoritmo de sua preferência. [Aqui tem um exemplo com SHA1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41827/seguran%C3%A7a-com-chave-em-asp-net-mvc/41838#41838).

A escolha do que usar depende da sua necessidade. Se é reversível, se é rápido, se é muito difícil de quebrar, e assim por diante.

[O *namespace* `System.Security.Cryptography`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx) tem também muitas opções que você pode usar.

Comment: eu não recomendaria aquele exemplo que você linkou. Ele não faz o "key stretching" e comparar o MAC com `==` é vulnerável a timing attacks.

Comment: É só um exemplo do que dá pra fazer. A ideia é dar ideias.

Comment: Há algum metodo que gere um hash sempre aleatório, não reversivel, e que possa haver validação (senha / hash) e que gere sempre uma string de tamanho único?

Comment: Sim, [todos da família SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), por exemplo.

Comment: Se for pra só dar idéia, prefiro dar a idéia de aproveitar uma biblioteca pronta, como bcrypt :) Quando se trata de criptografia, é muito fácil fazer cagada ao tentar programar as coisas você mesmo.