# AspNet MVC database first ou code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, code-first, database-first

Eu tenho um projeto AspNet MVC 5 em que vou utilizar o Owin e identity, eu precisei customizar o identity(atributos e relações) para atender a minhas necessidades, porém eu já tenho todas as tabelas do banco "prontas" (não populadas), nessas tabelas já existentes eu vou criar relacionamentos para minha tabela identity AspNetUsers. Ai esta o problema isso é errado? Quais os problemas em se fazer isso? Sinto como se estivesse misturando databasefirst com codefirst e de fato não sei se isso é certo ou não, quais os problemas podem surgir ao ter que se mexer no código fist das classes do identiy? Quais os problemas ao se mexer nas colunas do meu banco já pronto criado via databasefirst?

Comment: Eu não vejo nenhum problema em fazer isso, usa codefirst para tudo (eu prefiro pelo menos) e muda a string de conexão do identity para a do seu banco, ele já vai criar tudo lá. (Se você usou o template padrão é só fazer isso), a partir daí é fazer relacionamentos.

Answer (score 2):

> Ai esta o problema isso é errado?

Não. O Identity foi feito para trabalhar com um nível de customização quase que completo. Não apenas é possível definir mais relacionamentos de Usuário com outras entidades como até trocar o nome da tabela no banco de dados.

> Quais os problemas em se fazer isso?

Ao que eu saiba, não há problema em relacionar usuários com outras entidades do seu sistema.

> Sinto como se estivesse misturando databasefirst com codefirst e de fato não sei se isso é certo ou não, quais os problemas podem surgir ao ter que se mexer no código fist das classes do identiy?

Se eu entendi, aparentemente você quer aproveitar um banco de dados que já existe com o ASP.NET Identity. Aí eu diria que pode ser problemático. Explico:

O ASP.NET Identity implementa algumas funcionalidades que dificilmente seu banco já existente terá, como o tratamento das senhas. A não ser que seu banco tenha **exatamente** as mesmas informações, funcionaria sem problemas, o que é muito difícil porque outros *frameworks* [não implementam o mesmo esquema de criptografia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43606/qual-criptografia-usada-pelo-asp-net-identity/43607#43607).

Neste caso, é melhor implementar um esquema próprio e não usar o Identity.

> Quais os problemas ao se mexer nas colunas do meu banco já pronto criado via databasefirst?

Depende de vários fatores. Um sistema legado poderia parar de funcionar, por exemplo.

Para bases que já existem, não é recomendado deixar o Entity Framework gerenciar o banco. O *Database First* não gerencia o banco de dados por *design*.

Comment: Sim eu já tenho um banco de dados "feito" mas eu vou trocar toda a parte de permissões e usuários para trabalhar com identity. Um problema que eu tenho agora por exemplo é que não sei como utilizar a mesma conexão com o banco de dados, tanto para as classes do Identity que criei via codeFirst quanto para as classes criadas pelo VS via DataBaseFirst. Eu não cheguei a utilizar transações ainda, mas acho que terei problemas. Como poderia por exemplo utilizar a mesma conexão ?

Comment: O melhor é você usar a mesma *connection string* para identity e banco, criando as novas tabelas que o ASP.NET Identity precisa para trabalhar. Isto pode ser feito criando um novo projeto com ASP.NET Identity em cima de um banco de dados vazio. Aí você faz um script e executa este script no seu banco antigo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta rápida, mas eu não entendi direito... Eu tenho um identity customizado, com umas relações e propriedades a mais.O que eu faria seria criar um novo projeto e nele criar somente meu identity customizado. Gerar um SQL desse identity e  colocar via databaseFirst no meu projeto real?

Comment: ...e colocar **via script** no seu banco de dados. *Database First* considera que é o usuário que cuida do banco, e não o Entity Framework com Identity.

Comment: Ok, só mais uma duvida: tendo eu criado via script sql essas tabelas do identity no meu banco de dados e depois criado suas respectivas classes via ADO Entity data Model como eu estenderia da classe IdentityUser, para dispor de todos os benefícios do identity? É isso que vc propôs ou estou enganado?

Comment: É exatamente isso.